# Perform segue with no back button?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

Is there a way to perform a segue from one of your viewcontroller burried deep within your navigation controller than, when the segue is called, prevents the "back" button from showing up? The justification for this is that after going that deep into the product, we'd rather the user not be able to go back and mess something up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the view that should hide the back button, all you have to do is add this line in `viewDidLoad`.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: That hides the back button, but it adds another button with the specific name now?

Comment: @Darkenor then you must be instantiating a new leftBarButtonItem somewhere, check and make sure you don't have leftItemsSupplementBackButton called anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In your `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` you can call `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];`

Comment: That view controller could have a property that toggles if that line should be called or not, just set it in your prepareForSegue.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like it better to set the hide back button in the source UIViewController instead of the destination UIViewController. This allows you to deffer per segue to enable or disable back navigation. In the `viewDidLoad` you will not be able to see which segue was used to instantiate the UIViewController.

Therefore use prepare for segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToHideBackButtonIdentifier"]){
    [segue.destinationViewController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform segue as "Show Detail" not just "Show" and the new view will replace the current one

[image]

Comment: If you use Show Detail, the title of the NavController will not show. If you need it, you could add a NavBar to the ViewController you "Show"